# Convert PHP file tree array to array of relative paths

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filetree

I need to take a multidimensional array that defines a file tree structure and convert it to an array of relative paths.  I see plenty of answers on how to do the opposite.

I need this:

```
$file_tree = [
  'img',
  'js' => [
    'src',
    'min',
    'libraries' => ['jquery.js']
  ],
  'src' => [
    'controller' => ['user']
  ]
];
```

To become this:

```
$file_paths = ['img','js/src','js/min','js/libraries/jquery.js','src/controller/user']
```

Comment: Do you have any starting code you tried?

Comment: Please come with some code snippets. Then only we can help you friend

Comment: I did not provide any starter code because I wanted to see what solution someone might suggest knowing only the objective, without being influenced by my broken code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion.

Make a `processArray($o, $a, $f, $b = false)` The parameters are

`$o` - input array

`$a` - accumulator array

`$f` - file path accumulator

`$b` - this is to check if the function is first called

```
function processArray($o, $a = array(), $f = array() , $b = true){
    foreach( $o as $k => $v ) {
        if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
            $f[] = $k;
            if ( $b ) $f = array($k);
            $a = processArray( $v, $a, $f, false );
        } else {
            $r = implode('/',$f);
            $a[] = $r === '' ? $v : $r . '/' . $v;
        }
    }

    return $a;
}

$result = processArray( $file_tree ); //Call the function

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => img
    [1] => js/src
    [2] => js/min
    [3] => js/libraries/jquery.js
    [4] => src/controller/user
)
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help @daniel_lowetz :)